# Hibernate: Issue with CascadeType.REMOVE

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm developing a RESTful web application (using hibernate and mysql), specs of which are as below:

1. two tables in the database, tableA and tableB.
2. tableA has columns named col1A and col2A
3. tableB has columns named col1B, col2B and col1A; this last column (col1A) being the foreign key, mapping into the primary key of tableA.

The JAVA classes corresponding to the tables are defined as:

```
class tableA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlTransient
    private int col1A;

    private string col2A;

    // getters and setters
}

class tableB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlTransient
    private int col1B;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "col1A", referencedColumnName = "col1A", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private tableA tableAObj;

    private string col2B;

    // getters and setters
    // There is a getter and setter for the col1A field as well.
}
```

When I delete a row from the tableA, I assume that the rows in tableB that reference the row being deleted should be deleted by themselves (because of CascadeType.REMOVE). However, I get the following exception:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`pack1`.`tableB`, CONSTRAINT `FK27B8B255168D05` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`col1A`) REFERENCES `tableA` (`col1A`))

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Update**:

Some changes: I've added annotation in tableA like so:

```
 @XmlTransient
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true)
 private List<Test> tableB;
```

Still I get the same exception as before.

I'm removing the row using EntityManger's remove operation:

```
em.remove(t)
```

Comment: You should create mapping of TableB in TableA (`@OnetoMany`). And annotate this set `@onDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.Cascade)`

Comment: @michikot, I'm using entitymanager's remove to remove record from the table: em.remove(t), will the approach you specified work?

Comment: yes we have use it in our projects.please see my update\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, added the mappedBy attribute in tableA like so:

```
@XmlTransient
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "tableAObj")
private List<TableB> tableB;
```